# Validating form field in flutter

Tags: forms, validation, flutter

I have been trying to validate form in Flutter, the validation works but it destroys my design as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RARro.png)
I tried to validate first name field, the first design was like the last name design but it destroyed when showing error message.

The code for my `TextFormField`s is here:

```
_showText('First Name'),
Container(
  height: 50.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      //labelText: 'First Name',
      hintText: 'e.g Ali',
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
      ),
    ),
    validator: (value){
      if(value.isNotEmpty) {
        return null;
      } else return 'First Name is required';
    },
  ),
),
```

Someone Show me what is wrong with my design?

Comment: remove container height. following line.  height: 50.0,

Answer (score 1):

Your `height` constraint in the `Container` is causing problems. Just remove that line and it should be fine

Comment: Indeed that was the problem and now when i removed it is working fine .Thank you very much, but how about if i want to specify the height?

Comment: I don't think you should specify a height, it will always fit to the minimum required height anyway